# Parse CSV from one cell to rows & columns

Tags: excel, api, rest, csv

Having trouble getting my API call to land in excel correctly.  It's currently coming in as one cell, comma delimited, making it very difficult to separate by row and column...please help!
[Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Med.png)

```
'Call for report
Set MyRequest2 = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
URLReport = ("https://secure.saashr.com:443/ta/rest/v1/report/saved/18957188?company%3Ashortname=slszdr")
MyRequest2.Open "GET", URLReport, False
MyRequest2.setRequestHeader "Accept", "csv"
MyRequest2.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "1500"
MyRequest2.setRequestHeader "Authentication", "Bearer " & Token
MyRequest2.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
MyRequest2.Send
CSVReport = MyRequest2.ResponseText

'Place report in new sheet
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = ("Report " & Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = CSVReport
'Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, Comma:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection only returns the range of selected cells.  Most likely only cell A1 is selected. You can use Selection.CurrentRegion to expand the range to include all cells a list. ActiveSheet.UsedRange returns an the range starting with the first used cell and extending to the last used cell.

> Selection.address: $A$1
>
> Selection.CurrentRegion.address: $A$1:$L$1500
>
> ActiveSheet.UsedRange: $A$1:$L$1500

There is no need to select or activate cells. I prefer to act on the range directly and not through the Selection object.

### This will split the Comma Separated Value into columns

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False`

Add this code to determine the data type of CSVReport.

```
If IsArray(CSVReport) Then
    MsgBox "X: " & UBound(CSVReport) & " Y: " & UBound(CSVReport), vbInformation, "CSVReport is an Array"
Else 
    MsgBox "X: " & Split(Text1.Text, Chr(13)), vbInformation, "CSVReport is a String"
End If
```

In either case you'l going to have to Resize the destination range to fit the data.

Something like

> ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(x, y) = CSVReport

But the implementation will vary based on the data type and shape of CSVReport.

Comment: This does not produce a desirable result.  It just copies the same full text to the whole range.

Comment: Your code is only inserting 1 cell of data. If CSVReport has more that 1 row than TextToColumns.  Is CSVReport  a String or an Array?

Comment: I think it's an array. How can I tell 

Comment: So I have to parse this string of text which is comma delimited...this is the challenge